# Arguments for eclipse compiler in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-jdt, maven-compiler-plugin

In the Eclipse Compiler for Java standalone, I am able to log in XML the compilation info via a command-line atribute, as in this stub:

```
java -jar ecj-4.3.2.jar -log compile.xml <classpath,files>
```

However, when I use maven-compiler-plugin with plexus-compiler-eclipse, it seems I am unable to pass this argument to the compiler, and I am not sure the cause of this, whether the plugin's compiler is another one, it doesn't spawn new processes (i even tried the executable parameter), or other reason.

Here is the pom.xml section:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
      <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
      <!--<compilerArgument> -log compile.xml </compilerArgument>-->
      <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-log</arg>
        <arg>compile.xml</arg>
      </compilerArgs>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
      <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
   </configuration>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
         <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
         <version>2.3</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It also doesn't work when you use `<compilerArgument>-log compile.xml</compilerArgument>`?  I see that commented out in your question.

Comment: no, not really... I tried nearly every combination I could from the options presented in the compile:compile page of maven-compiler-plugin

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse implementation is `plexus-compiler-eclipse`, it doesn't accept `fork` argument, as it uses the internal jvm. So, it can only accept jvm options like `MAVEN_OPTS`.

However, the default implementation is `plexus-compiler-javac`, which supports custom `executable`. The workaround may like this: set `fork` to true, and specify the `executable`.

For wraper in bash, you can visit here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971000/3289354