# Have gradle build output same warnings as vscode java extension

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have a gradle build that I run from the command line. Sometimes I open and edit the project in vscode.

When I open a project in vscode, I get a bunch of warnings. When I build using gradle from the command line, I get none.

Is there a way I can have my gradle build trigger that exact same set of warnings the the vscode extension generates?

Comment: What warnings did you get in vscode?

Comment: Deadcode, deprecated method, unused imports, unused variable...among others. Not sure what tools the vscode plugin uses to generate these warnings.

Comment: These additional warnings could be from style check plugin. The vscode runs it.  ```https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html``` See if this one turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can get exactly the same warnings in Gradle as in VSCode, unless you can somehow tell Gradle to use VSCode as compiler.

That said, I'd always have

```
compileJava { 
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:all" 
}
```

in my `build.xml`

If that gets too noisy, you can reduce the lint level and just specify `-Xlint:deprecation`. See [the javac documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html) for the list of available lint options. (Search the page for "-Xlint:".)

You can even enable Javadoc linting with `-Xdoclint:all`; again see the documentation for what checks it supports.

Comment: Well vscode is not the java compiler. Obviously it utilizes another tool for generating the warnings. I am curious if it uses something that is part of the jdk.

Answer (score 0):

I too wanted the same warnings (and in fact to fail the build in the event of warnings). Having investigated previously I looked again and found this post.

The comment above about using a different compiler made me think - VSCode uses Eclipse Buildship under the hood. Which led me to Eclipse JDT and [Eclipse ECJ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core_Programmer_Guide/ECJ#A_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_ECJ).

Once I got this far, I began to find [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46328865) which indicated how it might work.

I started simple and found it worked. But as I started applying to more code, I got new errors. Notably to do with Lombok and latterly unknown suppression tokens (for checkstyle and PMD). This [maven implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971000) and this [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/ecj) documentation gave me more clues for Lombok. For the unknown suppression tokens I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/507) which just says that VSCode ignores it.

I used this [man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/ecj) to work out the parameters I needed to disable `warningToken` checks and also to fail on warnings.

It is noteworthy, that this may be slightly fragile with respect to [Gradle 8](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15942)

Anyway, now it won't even *compile* if there are errors. Of course you may not want that.

Put this in your `gradle.build` or main plugin under `./buildSrc`.

```
configurations {
    ecj
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    // This is the last version which works with Java 8. You can find more up to date versions
    ecj 'org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:3.26.0'
    // ...
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    def ecjMainClass = 'org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main'
    javaCompiler.set(provider { null })

    options.headerOutputDirectory.set(provider { null })
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.with {
        executable = 'java'
        jvmArgs = [
            '-classpath', project.configurations.ecj.asPath,
            // The following two lines make lombok work but assume you're
            // using the `io.freefair.lombok` plugin
            "-javaagent:${configurations.lombok.asPath}".toString(),
            "-Xbootclasspath/a:${configurations.lombok.asPath}".toString(),
            ecjMainClass
        ]
    }
    // Ignore unknown suppressions
    options.compilerArgs << '-warn:-warningToken'

    // Total fail if there are errors - remove this if you just want warnings
    options.compilerArgs << '-failOnWarning'
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```